# Divisibility of an expression by 323

Tags: divisibility

Determine the number of integers $n$ with $1\leq n\leq 2017$ such that $323$ divides the expression $20^n + 16^n - 3^n - 1$.

So first, the expression is an even number (not sure what that does).

Then I try $323=20\times 16 + 3\times 1$ and so I get a $X = \frac{(20^n + 16^n)-(3^n+1)}{20\times 16} +3\times 1$ and then I don't know how to factor something out or something.

And so I try pressing some values in calculator and I see all even numbers for $n$ work so I get 1008, which is correct but how do I do this like logically?

Comment: $323=17\times19$ surely?

Comment: oh no i forgot that, oh no ok i tot it was prime

Comment: I Find it hard to believe 1008 cases work !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$20^n\equiv 3^n\mod 17$$ and $$16^n\equiv (-1)^n\mod 17$$ so we have
$$20^n+16^n-3^n-1\equiv 3^n+(-1)^n-3^n-1\mod 17$$ and
$$20^n\equiv 1\mod 19$$ and $$16^n\equiv (-3)^n\mod 19$$ so we get
$$1+(-3)^n-3^n-1\mod 19$$ 
Can you finish?

Comment: Very nice answer Prof! ٩(˘◡˘)۶ –

Comment: The main thing is that your problem was solved, have a nice evening!

Comment: Not MY problem lol. Although I was surprised at first that it divides So often. :) Im not the Op but Thanks anyway lol

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Since $323=17\times 19$ by CRT we need to solve

- $20^n + 16^n - 3^n -1\equiv 0 \iff 3^n + (-1)^n - 3^n -1\equiv 0 \\\iff (-1)^n+1\equiv 0 \mod{17}$
- $20^n + 16^n - 3^n -1\equiv 0 \iff 1 + (-3)^n - 3^n -1\equiv 0\\\iff-2\cdot3^n\equiv0 \mod{19}$

Comment: Ok thank you but i think it should be (-3)^n -3^n in the end line?

Comment: @shgdhfgxbcv ops...yes of course! fixed